# Can you limit three.js device orientation controls the same as orbit controls

Tags: ios, three.js, device-orientation

Simple question, Device Orientation Controls doesn't seem too well documented. 
I know with orbit controls you can do stuff like this:

```
 controls.minPolarAngle = Math.PI / 2 - 0.2;
 controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI / 2 - 0.7;
```

Is there something similar for device orientation controls?

Comment: does anybodyyyy knowwww

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:
`beta = Math.max(this.minPolarAngle, Math.min(this.maxPolarAngle, beta));`
 in your update function before calling the `setObjectQuaternion`.